# Как определить иной массив строк для TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

Уважаемые разработчики. Пишу своё первое полноценное приложение на android, что-то вроде текстовой игры. Столкнулся с небольшой проблемой.

Есть TextView, при нажатии на который выводится следующий текст. При появлении текста с определенным индексом выводится список вариантов ответа (ещё два TextView).

Проблема заключается в том, что после нажатие на один один из вариантов ответа не могу определить другой массив строк для основного TextView.

Возможно написал не совсем понятным языком, да и сам код возможно не очень, но буду рад помощи. Заранее спасибо.

```
        mMainTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //индексация массива
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % mainTextArray.meetingTextsArray.length;

             //массив строк с изменением индекса при клике
            int text = mainTextArray.meetingTextsArray[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
            mMainTextView.setText(text);
            //при нужном индексе всплывают варианты ответа(ещё 2 textview)
            if(mCurrentIndex == 1) {
                showChoiceButtons(R.string.meeting_left_text, R.string.meeting_right_text,
                        mMainTextView);

                leftChoiceButtonPressed();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void leftChoiceButtonPressed() {

 //первый вариант ответа, затем нужно изменить массив строк для основного
 //textview
    mLeftChoiceTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMainTextView.setText("Тестим");
        }
    });
}

    private void showChoiceButtons(int leftButton, int rightButton, View view) {
    //показать всплывающие варианты ответа
    mLeftChoiceTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mRightChoiceTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mLeftChoiceTextView.setText(leftButton);
    mRightChoiceTextView.setText(rightButton);
    view.setClickable(false);
}

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".BookActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main_text"
    android:layout_width="218dp"
    android:layout_height="217dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/left_choice_text"
    android:layout_width="114dp"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/right_choice_text"
    android:layout_width="114dp"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

Comment: "после нажатия на один один из вариантов ответа не могу определить другой массив строк для основного TextView."
А на словах если, после нажатия на `mLeftChoiceTextView` что дальше вы хотите чтоб произошло? чтоб в `mMainTextView` при клике массив `mainTextArray.meetingTextsArray` поменялся на другой?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите менять массив, текст главного `textView` и текст на остальных 2 `textView` при клике на, например, левый `textView`.

Я бы сделал так:

```
changeTextArrays(0); // 0 - начальное значение 
mMainTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // отсюда перенесено несколько строк в метод changeTextArrays
        //при нужном индексе всплывают варианты ответа(ещё 2 textview)
        if(mCurrentIndex == 1) {
            showChoiceButtons(R.string.meeting_left_text, R.string.meeting_right_text,
                    mMainTextView);

            //leftChoiceButtonPressed(); // тут только устанавливается действие клика. Поэтому его можно вызвать 1 раз, поэтому написал после mMainTextView.setOnClickListener
        }
    }
});
leftChoiceButtonPressed();
}

private void leftChoiceButtonPressed() {
    mLeftChoiceTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMainTextView.setText("Тестим");// поменяли главный текст, да?

            //по логике надо ещё названия левой и правой текстов поменять на те,
            //что должны отобразиться при выборе левого клика:
            showChoiceButtons(R.string.left_text_новый, R.string.right_text_новый,
                    mMainTextView);

            //на счёт смены массива. Предложу такой вариант:
            changeTextArrays(1); // в аргументах к методу можно передать условие для смены массива  
        }
    });
}

// этот метод можно вызвать до mMainTextView.setOnClickListener(...
// так как я перенёс строки с индексами из mMainTextView.setOnClickListener
private void changeTextArrays(int type){

// у нас будет временный массив, куда будем присваивать другие массивы в зависимости от условий (например, type)
// tempTextArray - массив, с типом, как у mainTextArray 
if(type == 0){
        tempTextArray = mainTextArray; // начальный массив, без изменений
    } else if(type == 1){
        //тут меняем массив 
        tempTextArray = mainTextArray2; // массив, который должен работать после клика 
    } else if(type == 2){
        //тут меняем массив 
        tempTextArray = mainTextArray3; // массив 3й и так далее
    }

    //индексация массива
        mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex + 1) % tempTextArray.meetingTextsArray.length;

        //массив строк с изменением индекса при клике
        int text = tempTextArray.meetingTextsArray[mCurrentIndex].getTextResId();
        mMainTextView.setText(text);
}
```

Но этот пример также нуждается в доработке, например, клик по левому textView будет вызывать метод с одним и тем же значением `changeTextArrays(1);` поэтому можно заменить цифру 1 на глобальную переменную, которая будет также изменяться, как и массив в методе `changeTextArrays`

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вы всё правильно поняли. Ваши поправки очень помогут!

Comment: @Geronimo если ответ был наиболее полезным, чем остальные, в будущем не забудьте отметить его, как правильный. Проверьте его. Плюсую ваш рейтинг за вашу старательность в программировании). Также если нужна дополнительная помощь по этому вопросу, спрашивайте